# Android Volley: Why is response.statusCode highlighted and how do I check if an API response is successful?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I wan to check if the status code = 200 or if the response is succesful or not but i keep geting this errorin the reponse.statusCode.

```
private fun signUp() {
    val email = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.emailEditText).text.toString()
    val password = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.passwordEditText).text.toString()

    val url = "http://airbulance-api-tecnosam.koyeb.app/api/v1/users"
    val requestBody = JSONObject().apply {
        put("email", email)
        put("password", password)
    }

    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        url,
        requestBody,
        { response ->
            val statusCode = response.statusCode
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                val user = Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), User::class.java)

                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d("Airbulance", "User signed up successfully")

                    // Save the token as a shared preference
                    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
                    editor.putString("token", user.token)
                    editor.apply()
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Airbulance", "Error signing up: $statusCode")
            }
        },
        { error ->
            Log.e("Airbulance", "Error signing up: ${error.message}")
        }
    )

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

I was trying to check if the response from the API was successful or not.
What do i do?

Comment: what is the error?